# Practice makes perfect: is makes an intransitive?

Tags: verbs

> Practice **makes** perfect. (James Joyce, Ulysses)

Is *makes* an intransitive or transitive verb?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Practice makes perfect* is an idiom that is taken verbatim. It means "Doing something over and over again is the only way to learn to do it well."

It is not a "normal" grammatical construct. For example "Exercise makes fit" (which is grammatically similar) is not correct in modern English usage.

If you wish to use this phrase, use it exactly because it is an idiom. Do not try to derive grammatical rules from idioms; they do not follow grammatical rules in the same way that other parts of English do.

Answer (score 1):

It is idiomatic, but I'm guessing it's origin is ellptical - perhaps, "Practice makes you perfect [at some skill]".